# Local storage save and retrieve text input value

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage, storage

So I am trying to save the value of a text input field after a user enters in it, then once the page is reloaded when clicking action2 it pushes the saved value into the value of the text input field. As you can tell from my code I do not have much knowledge on this subject but I am struggling through a class for it and have tried everything I can think of!

Thanks in Advance!

```
<input type="text" id="header" name="header" value="name">
<p>
    <button onclick="action()" type="button">Save me!</button>
</p>
<p>
    <button onclick="action2()" type="button">Remember me!</button>
</p>

<script>
    function action() {
        localStorage.setItem(header, name)
    } 

    function action2() {
        localStorage.getItem(header, name)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @praguan, [please don't link to w3schools](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
<input type="text" id="header" name="header" value="name">
<p><button onclick="action()" type="button">Save me!</button></p>
<p><button onclick="action2()" type="button">Remember me!</button></p>

<script>
    function action() {
        window.localStorage['header'] = document.getElementById('header').value;
    }

    function action2() {
        document.getElementById('header').value = window.localStorage['header'];
    }
</script>
```